# Права ли Справка Грамоты.ру (см.), приговаривая к постановке запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

[Вопрос № 277787](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20277787)

> Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания в предложении "Всё
>   что нужно – чтобы брелок находился внутри автомобиля".

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> *Всё, что нужно, – чтобы брелок находился внутри автомобиля*.
>
> ---

Мучаюсь над похожей структурой:

*Всё, что есть здесь связно сказанного, – труд моего редактора.*

(Предложение в оригинале не столь убогое, редактировать не надо; это просто "рыба", каркас.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Всё, **что есть здесь связно сказанного**, – труд моего редактора.*

Это тема "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым".

Всё – субстантивированное местоимение, распространенное придаточным предложением.

А у Грамоты в позиции сказуемого находится придаточное предложение. сравнить: *Всё, что нужно, – это расположение брелка  внутри автомобиля*.